# Design some resistor with operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I will wish that using a variable voltage source (via a potentiometer) whatever happens to my input voltage (it can vary depending on certain conditions between 4V DC and 6V DC) I have 5V output. In addition, I want to have a gain of 2.

So here is the diagram I had thought of, and I would like to know if it is possible to do what I want, and how, because via my calculations I found a reference voltage on the terminal "+" too high compared to to my 5V.

[image: Schematic]

Thus, R1 = 50k, R2 = 100k, the potentiometer is represented by the variable voltage source (between 0 and 5V DC).

I must then determine R3 and R4 so that Vs is equal to 5V by modifying the output potentiometer when Ve = 4V DC or Ve = 6V DC

P.S.: Supply for the operational amplifier is +15-0V single supply.

Comment: Your design requirements don't quite make sense to me.  You want the output to always be 5V, no matter what the input is.  You want a gain of 2 for the amplifier, and you want a variable resistor to make the output always be 5V.  Sorry.  Does not compute.

Comment: @JRE I think I wasn't enought clear.

The potentiometer will allow me to adjust the electrical 0 of my sensor compared to my mechanical 0. After that, my output will change between X and Y volt, but center on 5V.

It's more clear ?

Comment: R3-R4 voltage divider is not necessary in your case...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Thanks for your answer. I think it was not important to. But, I want to find the VRef to have Vs = 5V when Ve = 4V; but my calcul doesnt work (Vs-Vref = R2/R2*(Ve-VRef))

That's good formula ?

Comment: @Benjamin M, If R3 and R4 are removed, then Vout = Vpot*(R2/R1+1) - Ve*R2/R1 because this circuit is a combination of non-inverting and inverting ampifier and the superposition principle can be applied. Also, it can be thought of as an inverting ampifier with a "lifted" virtual ground (bias voltage).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist So I can't use 5V ref for my potentiometer ? (If Ve = 6V, 3Vpot - 2*6 = 5 VPot = 5.66)

Comment: @Benjamin M, You can consider the input and output voltage variations referenced to the potentiometer voltage Vpot acting as another ("lifted", virtual, artificial) ground. So, if Vpot = 5 V and Ve varies from 4 V to 6 V, you have an input voltage varying from -1 V to +1 V in regards to Vpot = 5 V. It is amplified -R2/R1 = 100/50 = 2 times; so the op-amp output voltage Vout, will vary from +2 V to -2 V in regards to Vpot = 5 V... or from 7 V to 3 V in regards to the initial real ground. Maybe my formula above is not correct in this single-supplied configuration.

Comment: This question is... a bit of a catastrophe. You quote Vs but do not show it anywhere on your schematic. You write "potentiometer" on a voltage supply which is definitely not a potentiometer. I think your best bet is to give up on an initial implementation altogether and tell us exactly what you need: when the input potentiometer is at 0%, the output is 4V; when the input potentiometer is at 100%, the output is at 6V?

Comment: I think OP wants something like those opamps which _auto-zero_ their output offset voltage at switch on. In OP's case, at switch on, the sensor has a bias voltage between 4 V and 6 V. They want the output to be zeroed (or 5 volted). Once the initial bias is removed, all further input voltage variation should appear at the output with a gain of 2 riding over the 5 V.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a circuit that implements:

> whatever happens to my input voltage (it can vary depending on certain conditions between 4V DC and 6V DC) I have 5V output

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmoOis.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It involves taking some scissors and disconnecting your input voltage entirely. I suspect that's not what you actually want; that being the case there's a pressing need for you to edit your question.

If you actually want a gain of 2 where your input ranges between 4-6V and your output is centered around 5V, your output would range between 3-7V and you would have (any ratiometric multiple of):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqiBiv.png)</sup>

[image: dc sweep]

Who knows how you want a potentiometer to factor into this. Maybe you don't actually need the original 4-6 pot voltage, and you *only* need a range of 3-7V, in which case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffBeaL.png)</sup>

[image: pot sweep]

Or maybe you still want a fixed gain of 2 on an input Ve, and want your pot to represent an adjustable reference to subtract from this voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh8gcH.png)</sup>

For five different potentiometer positions, this yields

[image: multiplot]

Isn't wild guessing fun?